# Is there any relationship between step-wise multiple Regression analysis results and ANOVA results?

Tags: regression, anova

I performed two separate regression analyses by dividing my total sample into 'Male' and 'Female' samples, that resulted into different % of variances of variables (e.g for male the percent variance in the 'school achievement scores' due to 'teaching' is 20%, while for female students the variance of 'teaching' is 40%).

Now, in 2-way ANOVA results there found no sig. main as well as interaction effects of the 'Gender' and 'Teaching' over the 'achievement scores'.
(Note: the t-test is also insignificant for 'Gender')

Are my results correct?
Isn't there should be some interaction effect of both? As 'Teaching' is playing role in 'achievement scores'.

Comment: Why did you divide your sample in two? Two regression models on separated data are probably going to give different results than one ANOVA on the whole sample.

Answer (score 0):

Comparing the values of $R^2$ is not really telling you about the phenomenon you are interested in. It is perfectly possible for there to be the same model underlying male and female behaviour yet the $R^2$ values could differ if one sex has more variable scores than the other. If you post the output from your three regression models people may be able to give you further advice.